# All the values should be aligned to one row in the web page

Tags: html

I am designing an web application,That has one label,textbox and button. All three should be aligned in one row, but it's all coming into new row.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right" for="lists">lists:</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="lists" required>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4 top-space-30">
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

I have tried one more way with creating tables also

```
<div class="row-fluid top-space-20">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <th>label</th>
                        <th>textbox</th>
                        <th>button</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right" for="list">list:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="list" required>
                                <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
```

I thought if all the fields are coming in one row I can somewhat hide the headers and table from the page. That didn't work well.

If you see the label, textbox and button are coming in each row. I tried using tables that also didn't work well.

What is my expected output is all should be aligned in one row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code. Instead of form-group use input-group it will work for you

```
  <div class="input-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right" for="lists">lists:</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="lists" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="form-inline">
 <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
   <label for="lists">lists:</label>
   <input class="form-control" type="text" id="lists" required>
 </div>
 <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
</form>
```